# How to get request.GET.get('variable') in multiple value

Tags: javascript, python, django

> How to get the multiple value in input form html to django.
> I only get the first input value Enroll but when I click the second button which is Payment I cannot get the value also in third input I don't know if the JavaScript is the problem or in my views.py  - Beginner programmer :(

html and javascript

```
<html>
....
<script>
function newAppend(name, img, side){

      const msgCHAT = `
      <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
          <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${img})"></div>
            <div class="msg-bubble">
              <div class="msg-info">
                <div class="msg-info-name">${name}</div>
                <div class="msg-info-time">${formatDate(new Date())}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="msg-text"><p>How can I help you?</p></div>
              <br>
              <div class="butnew">
                <button type="submit" class="input-bot" name="input_text" id="inputBot" value="Enroll">Enrollment</button>
                <button type="submit" class="input-bot" name="input_text" id="inputBot" value="Pay">Payment</button>
                <button type="submit" class="input-bot" name="input_text" id="inputBot" value="Hi">Hi Username</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
      msgerChat.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", msgCHAT);
      msgerChat.scrollTop += 500;

      // ===================================================================

      const msgerInputTwo = get(".input-bot");

      document.getElementById("inputBot").addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const msgTextTwo =  msgerInputTwo.value;
      appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "right", msgTextTwo);
      botResponse(msgTextTwo);     
    });

    }

function botResponse(rawText) {
      // Bot Response
      $.get("/chatbot/post", {input_text: rawText }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(rawText);
        console.log(data);
        const msgText = data;
        appendMessage(BOT_NAME, BOT_IMG, "left", msgText);
      });

    }
</script>

</html>
```

views.py

```
def chatbot_process(request):
  ..... 

    message = request.GET.get('input_text') 
    message = message.lower()
    ints = predict_class(str(message))
    response = get_response(ints, intents)
    response = str(response)
    return HttpResponse(response)


def chatbot(request):
    return render(request, "chatbot/chatbot.html")
```

URLS.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('train/', views.train_data, name='chatbot-train'),
    path('chatbot/', views.chatbot, name='chatbot-chatbot'),
    path("post/", views.chatbot_process, name='post'),
]
```

Comment: maybe `request.GET.getlist('variable')`

Comment: >Not working :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple item of same variable in your forms, You can get it in a `array`

Try this way:

```
request.GET.getlist('variable')
# ['value one', 'value two']
```